# Cannot use a scalar value as an array

Tags: php, array

tengo un array y necesito ordenarlo, tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php

// Matriz asociativa para mapear id y posición
$hash = [];
// Arreglo de resultados
$datos = [];

// Obtenemos un arreglo con las líneas del archivo
$lineas = file('C:\voto.txt');
foreach ($lineas as $linea) {

    // Extraemos los datos de la línea
    list($id, $tipo) = explode('|', trim($linea));
    $contador = 1;

    // Si aún no hemos agregado el id al hash
    if (!isset($hash[$id])) {
        // Guardamos en el hash el id y la posicion en el arreglo de datos
        $hash[$id] = count($datos);

        // Guardamos el id en el arreglo de datos
        $datos[] = [
            'id'=>$id,
            'tipo'=>$tipo, 
            'contador'=>$contador,
        ];
    } else {
        // Sumamos al contador del id guardado 1
        $datos[$hash[$id]]['contador']++;
    }
}

//var_export($datos);

foreach ($datos as $key => $row) {
        $contador[$key] = $row['contador'];
    }

    array_multisort($contador, SORT_DESC, $datos);

    echo json_encode($datos);
?>
```

El código me da los siguientes errores:

> Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array on line 36
>
> Warning: array_multisort(): Argument #1 is expected to be an array or
> sorting flag that has not already been specified on line 39

Si me pudieran ayudar a solucionar estos errores por favor.
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ambas advertencias se deben a que no has definido a la variable `$contador` como un arreglo.

#### Solución:

```
// ...
$contador = [];
foreach ($datos as $key => $row) {
    $contador[$key] = $row['contador'];
}
// ...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Marcos sin tu ayuda no lo hubiera sacado adelante. Me funciona perfectamente. Muy grande este foro! Saludos.